# Is there any way (without using third party solutions) to integrate Salesforce and ServiceNow?

Tags: salesforce, integration, servicenow

My specific use case is to integrate the both CRMs such that whenever a new Lead record is created in Salesforce, it should automatically be displayed in ServiceNow. I tried using Salesforce Spoke but it is only limited to Accounts, Cases, Contracts and Opportunity objects. I specifically need it for Leads and I am looking for a free solution with no limits on the number of records imported. Any ideas or solutions or ways on how to implement this? I need ideas.